# Calculating the joint probability of n events from a sample sequence of occurrences

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, bioinformatics

I'm writing an algorithm to take in a sample list of sequences of events, calculate 1-step transitional probabilities from the sequences, forward or in reverse, then calculate the joint probability of n events occurring from those conditional probabilities.

Eg. if the sample list of sequences is:

> ['TTAGCAGTCAGT', 'TCAGCGTTCGACTGA']

`cond_probs()` produces a dictionary `{'AT': n1, 'AG': n2, 'AA': n3, 'AC': n4, ... , 'TC': n16}`, where, for one, `n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 = 1`, from those sequences. In reverse, the transitional probabilities are calculated with the sequences in reverse.

With that dictionary, `exp_joint_probs()` produces another dictionary which, when n = 3, looks like `{'TTA': m1, 'TTC': m2, ..., 'GAC': m64}`, where `'TTA'` is calculated by `P('T') * P('TT') * P('TA')`. In reverse, it is `P('A') * P('AT') * P('TT')`, but the dictionary entry should still be `'TTA'`.

I'm wondering if my algorithm could be cleaner. I feel that perhaps using Numpy would make it much nicer, so a word from a Numpy expert would be great. I'm also looking for help double-checking the math.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

def exp_joint_probs(seqList, n, reverse = 0):
    probs = {}
    counts = Counter(''.join(seqList))
    states = counts.keys()
    sumv = sum(counts.values())
    initProbs = {c: counts[c] / float(sumv) for c in counts}
    condProbs = cond_probs(seqList, reverse)
    paths = product(counts.keys(), repeat = n)
    for p in paths:
        p = ''.join(p)
        if reverse == 0:
            probs[p] = initProbs[p[0]] 
            for i in range(n - 1):
                probs[p] = probs[p] * condProbs.get((p[i], p[i + 1]), 0)
        else:
            probs[p] = initProbs[p[2]]
            for i in range(n)[::-1][:-1]:
                probs[p] = probs[p] * condProbs.get((p[i], p[i - 1]), 0)
   return probs

def cond_probs(seqList, reverse = 0):
    counts = {}
    probs = {}
    for seq in seqList:
        if reverse:
            for i in range(len(seq))[::-1][:-1]:
                counts[seq[i],seq[i - 1]] = counts.get((seq[i], seq[i - 1]), 0) + 1
        else:
            for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
                counts[seq[i],seq[i + 1]] = counts.get((seq[i], seq[i + 1]), 0) + 1
    states = list(set(k[0] for k in counts.keys()))
    for s in states:
        if reverse:
            sCounts = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in counts.items() if k[1] == s)
        else:
            sCounts = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in counts.items() if k[0] == s)
        sumv = sum(sCounts.values())
        probs.update({(k,float(v)/sumv) for (k, v) in sCounts.items()})
    return probs
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm just going to look at `cond_probs` here. You'll see that there's plenty in this function for one answer.

#### 1. Comments on your code

1. The line `return probs` has the wrong indentation. Copy/paste error?
2. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do and how do I call them? (The text from your question would be a good starting-point for docstrings.)
3. There are no test cases. This is the kind of code that would benefit from some [unit tests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) and/or [doctests](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).
4. You write, "`cond_probs()` produces a dictionary `{'AT': n1, 'AG': n2, 'AA': n3, 'AC': n4, ... , 'TC': n16}`" but when I run it the dictionary has tuples for keys, not strings:

   ```
   >>> cond_probs(['AAC'])
   {('A', 'C'): 0.5, ('A', 'A'): 0.5}
   ```
5. I don't understand the behaviour when `reverse=True`. You write, "In reverse, the transitional probabilities are calculated with the sequences in reverse" but this doesn't seem to be the case:

   ```
   >>> cond_probs(['CAA'], reverse=True)
   {('A', 'A'): 1.0}
   ```

   What has happened to `C`? This looks wrong to me.

   If I were writing this, I'd implement `cond_probs` to run only in the forward direction; to do the reverse direction I would pass in reversed sequences.
6. Prefer using `True` and `False` for Booleans, not `1` and `0`. So the second parameter to `cond_probs` should be `reverse=False`.
7. Instead of:

   ```
   counts = {}
   # ...
   counts[X] = counts.get(X, 0) + 1
   ```

   use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and write:

   ```
   counts = Counter()
   # ...
   counts[X] += 1
   ```

   (But see below for how to use [`collections.Counter.update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update).)
8. Instead of:

   ```
   range(len(seq))[::-1][:-1]
   ```

   write:

   ```
   range(len(seq) - 1, 0, -1)
   ```

   (But see below for how to avoid this.)
9. Prefer iteration over elements of sequences instead of iteration over their indexes. So instead of:

   ```
   for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
       counts[seq[i],seq[i + 1]] = counts.get((seq[i], seq[i + 1]), 0) + 1
   ```

   use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

   ```
   for t in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
       counts[t] += 1
   ```

   or, even more simply, using [`collections.Counter.update`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

   ```
   counts.update(zip(seq, seq[1:]))
   ```

   (If you are concerned about memory use, then you could use  [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and write `islice(seq, 1, None)` instead of `seq[1:]` to avoid the copy.)
10. In this code:

    ```
    for s in states:
        sCounts = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in counts.items() if k[0] == s)
    ```

    you iterate over the whole of `counts` for every state, collecting the ones you want. It would be more efficient to iterate only over the transitions from `s`. See below for how this would look.

#### 2. Revised code

```
def cond_probs_2(sequences):
    """Calculate 1-step transitional probabilities from sequences.
    Return dictionary mapping transitions to probabilities.

    >>> sequences = ['ACABC', 'ABCAB']
    >>> sorted(cond_probs_2(sequences).items())
    ... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [(('A', 'B'), 0.75),
     (('A', 'C'), 0.25),
     (('B', 'C'), 1.0),
     (('C', 'A'), 1.0)]

    """
    counts = Counter()
    entries = set()
    for seq in sequences:
        entries.update(seq)
        for a, b in zip(seq, islice(seq, 1, None)):
            counts[a, b] += 1
    probs = {}
    for a in entries:
        suma = float(sum(counts[a, b] for b in entries))
        if suma != 0:
            probs.update(((a, b), counts[a, b] / suma) for b in entries
                         if counts[a, b])
    return probs
```

This is about 30% faster than your code:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from random import choice
>>> data = ''.join(choice('ACGT') for _ in range(1000000))
>>> cond_probs([data]) == cond_probs_2([data])
True
>>> timeit(lambda:cond_probs([data]), number=1) # yours
1.4706195190083236
>>> timeit(lambda:cond_probs_2([data]), number=1) # mine
0.9721288200234994
```

#### 3. Rewriting in NumPy

Here's how I'd go about this kind of task in NumPy. NumPy works best with fixed-size numeric data, so I'd encode the input as small integers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = 'TTAGCAGTCAGTTCAGCGTTCGACTGA'
>>> distinct = set(data)
>>> coding = {j:i for i, j in enumerate(distinct)}
>>> coding
{'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'T': 2, 'G': 3}
>>> coded_data = np.fromiter((coding[i] for i in data), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> coded_data
array([2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0,
       1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

(I've chosen the type `np.uint8` here because there are only four different characters in the input strings. You might need to choose a different type.)

Then you can encode adjacent pairs of numbers from 0–3 as a single number from 0–15, count the number of occurrences of each pair using [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), and decode the result using [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> n = len(distinct)
>>> pairs = coded_data[:-1] + n * coded_data[1:]
>>> counts = np.bincount(pairs, minlength=n*n).reshape(n, n)
>>> counts
array([[0, 3, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 3, 2],
       [0, 1, 3, 3],
       [4, 2, 1, 0]])
```

This array represents the transition table:

```
          source 
       │ A  C  T  G
     ──┼───────────
     A │ 0, 3, 1, 2
dest C │ 1, 0, 3, 2
     T │ 0, 1, 3, 3
     G │ 4, 2, 1, 0
```

You can then compute the transition probabilities by dividing each element by the sum of its column:

```
>>> counts / counts.sum(axis=0)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.125     ,  0.28571429],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.        ,  0.375     ,  0.28571429],
       [ 0.        ,  0.16666667,  0.375     ,  0.42857143],
       [ 0.8       ,  0.33333333,  0.125     ,  0.        ]])
```

Here's the above as a function:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

def cond_probs_np(sequences):
    """Calculate 1-step transitional probabilities from sequences.
    Return dictionary mapping transitions to probabilities.

    >>> sequences = ['ACABC', 'ABCAB']
    >>> sorted(cond_probs_np(sequences).items())
    ... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [(('A', 'B'), 0.75),
     (('A', 'C'), 0.25),
     (('B', 'C'), 1.0),
     (('C', 'A'), 1.0)]

    """
    distinct = set(chain.from_iterable(sequences))
    n = len(distinct)
    assert(n < 256)             # so that they will fit in an np.uint8
    coding = {j:i for i, j in enumerate(distinct)}
    counts = np.zeros((n, n))
    for seq in sequences:
        coded_seq = np.fromiter((coding[i] for i in seq), dtype=np.uint8)
        pairs = coded_seq[:-1] + n * coded_seq[1:]
        counts += np.bincount(pairs, minlength=n*n).reshape(n, n)
    totals = counts.sum(axis=0)
    totals[totals == 0] = 1     # avoid division by zero
    probs = counts / totals
    return {(a, b): p for a, b in product(distinct, repeat=2) 
            for p in (probs[coding[b], coding[a]],) if p}
```

And this is about seven times faster than your original code:

```
>>> cond_probs([data]) == cond_probs_np([data])
True
>>> timeit(lambda:cond_probs_np([data]), number=1)
0.2206433709943667
```

Comment: Checking this question three years on, I had missed this answer entirely somehow!

Answer (score 2):

Counting in Python is best done using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

The problem you have described sounds like a Markov chain, and the probabilities would best be represented as a [Markov chain transition matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example).  You could then obtain the joint probabilities using matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes - I'm aware it is a Markov chain! Would be pretty impressive I knew the phrase '1-step transition' without knowing that. But what you say isn't true. Matrix multiplication of transition matrices would result in n-step transition matrices, which give probabilities of going from one state to another in n steps, considering every possible state it can go through in between. Here I want specific states in between.